# How to run gsutil rsync without auth?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

`aws s3 sync` provides a parameter named `--no-sign-request`, so user can sync a publicly-visible bucket without any auth in advance.

`gsutil help anon` says that:

> gsutil users can access publicly readable data without obtaining
>     credentials. For example, the gs://uspto-pair bucket contains a number
>     of publicly readable objects, so any user can run the following command
>     without first obtaining credentials:
>
> gsutil ls gs://uspto-pair/applications/0800401*
>
> Users can similarly download objects they find via the above gsutil ls
>     command.

However, running this command without login makes gsutil report errors:

```
➜  mirror-docker git:(v2) gsutil ls 'gs://uspto-pair/applications/0800401*'
Your credentials are invalid. Please run
$ gcloud auth login
```

Currently, we are setting up a mirror for common buckets on gcloudstorage, and want to find a way to perform sync without auth in advance. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Prior using the gsutil tool, you need to authenticate yourself as per this: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil#before-you-begin which is one of the requirements. Even if you have a publicly accessible bucket and/or object you cannot unfortunately perform a sync without authentication in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@Steeve 's answer that authentication is required is correct. The following is a simple script to sync a publicly-visible bucket to local. Just create a new account with no bill method and a new project/key pair:

```
#!/bin/bash

# path: sync destination
# access_key_id: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#keys
# access_secret_id: Same as above
# project_id: The project name where you create a new key
# source: source googlestorage path. Example: gs://flutter_intra

mkdir -p "$LUG_path"
env "GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$LUG_access_key_id" "GS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY=$LUG_access_secret_key" ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil  -o "GSUtil:default_project_id=$LUG_project_id" -m rsync -d -r "$LUG_source" "$LUG_path"
```